# Saving to PDF loop file name issue

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I have a macro that loops through a list of values and saves each as a PDF with the name being the value in that list in cell A7. It is working perfectly as it is, but I am having trouble adjusting the file name to include the value in A6 as well. I am relatively new to using VBA so this is probably an easy fix. Here's the working code:

```
Dim myFolder As String
Dim myFileName As String

myFolder = "C:\Users\JonDoe\Documents\"

For Each dealer In Range("S8:S15")
        Range("A7").Value = dealer
        myFileName = dealer & ".pdf"
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        myFolder & myFileName, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Next
End Sub
```

I tried to add the value in A6 to myFileName like so:

```
Sub printDealerPagePDF()

Dim myFolder As String
Dim myFileName As String

myFolder = "C:\Users\JonDoe\Documents\"

For Each dealer In Range("S8:S15")
        Range("A7").Value = dealer
        Range("A6").Value = dealername
        myFileName = dealer & dealername & ".pdf"
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        myFolder & myFileName, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Next
End Sub
```

The macro still runs without error but it doesn't add "dealername" to the file name. What am I missing?

Comment: Your variable assignments are backwards.

Comment: This is not doing what you think it is doing.  It is not reading the dealer from A7 it is putting that value in the cell.  The value is coming from S8:S15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ***think*** * what you're trying to do is loop through each value from `Range("S8:S15")` into `A7` and print the page off as a PDF file.

You appear to be asking why the `dealername` isn't present. It's because you're not defining it. Where is it? Is there a formula in `A6` that is perhaps a `VLOOKUP` that gathers it?

In which case

```
 dealername = Range("A6").Value
 Range("A7").Value = dealer
```

should work.

However, if it's alongside each `dealer` (in the `Range("S8:S15")`) - perhaps in column `T` and needs to be loaded to `A6` before printing then use:

```
 dealername = dealer.Offset(0,1).Value
 Range("A7").Value = dealer
 Range("A6").Value = dealername
```

.*  But I could be entirely wrong

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing. And yes, "A6" is a VLOOKUP. I defined dealername and included dealername in "myFileName" and it worked for only the first value in Range("S8:S15"). After that, error pointing to the code starting "ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat."

Comment: Check that you haven't got characters in `A6` that can't be present in a filename?

Comment: Actually that was it! A lot of the names have "/" in them. I removed a few and tested it and it works.

Answer (score 3):

The Problem is that you do not actually assign a Value to "dealername".

```
dealername = Range("A6").Value
```

The above line of code should fix the problem. (The same goes for dealer)

Comment: Is that not the same as what I had?
    Range("A6").Value = dealername
I made the change you suggested and it worked for the first value but error'ed out for the rest of the list

Comment: @sleven The variable belongs to the left side and the "source" for the value belongs to the right side of the equation mark.

Comment: Does that also apply to "myFileName"?

Comment: Yes for every variable that you want assign a value to.
Left Side = Variable
Right Side = Value or Source for the Value the variable shall get.
@sleven